# how to set up the cron job on WHM server?

Tags: php, cron, whm

I am trying to set up a cron job on let's say example.com So, what I have php script right in public_html directory called cron_job.php I can run it easily right of the browser and I am sure it works.

But when I go to control panel on example.com then to cron jobs. I set up timing and path as following, but when time comes it does not work:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /home/vmax/public_html/cron_job.php
```

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: I does not show any errors, the code works just fine if I just run it from the browser. But when time comes for it as set in "cron jobs", it just does not get launched.

Comment: Ok. What OS are you using?

Comment: it is Linux based server

Comment: What does the cron job line look like? E.g. "54 9 2 7 3 <script>"

Comment: I am using "putty" to access it, so I do "crontab -l" to look it up and it says: 10 9 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/php -f /home/stahlinl/public_html/cron_autolead.php

Comment: try running `/usr/bin/php -f /home/vmax/public_html/cron_job.php` command through putty and see whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with following.

```
 /usr/bin/php -q /home/vmax/public_html/cron_job.php
```